# Amicable numbers on c#

Tags: c#, function

Today is my first question on stack overflow, thanks all for answers (My english is bad sorry).

Actually I work in program with it show me amicable number the 0 of 10000.
Program repeat numbers I don't understand why dont work good.

Picture:

284 AND 220 220 AND 284 How to delete repeat numbers?

[image]

Example of Amicable Numbers:

Divisors of 220 are 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 11, 20, 22, 44, 55 and 110: The sum of which is 284. And the sum of the divisors of 284 (1, 2, 4, 71 and 142) equals 220.

My code is:

```
class Program
{
    static int SumaDivisors(int nombre)
    {
        int suma;
        suma = 0;

        for (int contador = 1; contador < nombre; contador++)
        {
            if (nombre % contador == 0)
            {
                suma = suma + contador;
            }
        }
        return suma;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Busca els nombres amics entre 0 i 10000");
        int numero, suma1, suma2;

        for (numero = 1; numero < 10000; numero++)
        {

            suma1 = SumaDivisors(numero);
            suma2 = SumaDivisors(suma1);

            if (suma1 != numero && suma2 == numero)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Els nombre {0} i {1} són nombres amics", suma1, suma2);
            }
        }
            Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't visit imgur while at work. Can you instead copy the relevant information into the question?

Comment: In case this sounds familiar to anyone else, [this is problem #21 on Project Euler.](https://projecteuler.net/problem=21)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this case: `numero = 220`, then `suma1 = 284` and so `suma2 = 220`. Then consider `numero = 284`, then `suma1 = 220` and so `suma2 = 284`, the exact reverse. The same holds for the other pairs.

As for the solution, the simplest check you can do is to only print when `suma1 <= suma2`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Its really easy solution and its work correctly.

Comment: You need to store the pairs in a list, then remove duplicates from the list (or don't add numbers that already exist). int[,] data =  { { 284, 220 }, { 220, 284 }, { 1210, 1184 }, { 1184, 1210 }, { 2924, 2620 }, { 2620, 2924 }, { 5564, 5020 }, { 5020, 5564 }, { 6368, 6232 }, { 6232, 6368 } };

Comment: @MarcCM, be sure to accept this answer if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

It bounds to be found twice during the iteration. In order to eliminate repetition, either you can add a list to prevent the pair being displayed a second time :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Busca els nombres amics entre 0 i 10000");
    var list = new List<int>();
    int numero, suma1, suma2;

    for (numero = 1; numero < 10000; numero++)
    {
        suma1 = SumaDivisors(numero);
        suma2 = SumaDivisors(suma1);

        if (suma1 != numero && suma2 == numero && !list.Contains(suma1) && !list.Contains(suma2))
        {
            list.Add(suma1);
            list.Add(suma2);

            Console.WriteLine("Els nombre {0} i {1} són nombres amics", suma1, suma2);
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, great option, but I don't understand this solution. I new in c# world

Answer (score 0):

when the left operand of this if statement is TRUE [eg (suma1 != numero) ]:

```
if (suma1 != numero && suma2 == numero)
```

it does not then proceed to evaluate the second operand [eg (suma2 == numero) ] so that condition is not caught...it's called short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'm new on this world, I appreciate your lection.